How to clear the drawn rectangle in the mouse down event?
I tried to make Rectangle.Empty but it's not working.  it does nothing to the drawn rectangle. the drawn rectangle is stay and i want it to be deleted to start drawing a new rectangle.
_roiPicturebox = Rectangle.Empty;

_roiPicturebox is Rectangle.
private void PictureBoxFrame_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_tracking)
    {
        _startPoint = e.Location;
        _roiPicturebox = Rectangle.Empty; // Clear the existing rectangle
        pictureBoxFrame.Invalidate(); // Trigger repaint to clear the previous rectangle
        _drawing = true;
    }
}

private void PictureBoxFrame_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_drawing)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point endPoint = e.Location;
        _roiPicturebox = new Rectangle(Math.Min(_startPoint.X, endPoint.X),
                             Math.Min(_startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y),
                             Math.Abs(_startPoint.X - endPoint.X),
                             Math.Abs(_startPoint.Y - endPoint.Y));
        pictureBoxFrame.Invalidate(); // Trigger repaint
    }
}

private void PictureBoxFrame_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _drawing = false;
    _tracking = true;
}

private void PictureBoxFrame_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_roiPicturebox != Rectangle.Empty)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, _roiPicturebox);
    }
}


What's _tracking for and what sets it to false? -- BTW, you don't need those bool fields, just check whether the Button used to draw the shape is down. See the example here (for both things)
